# Get Input from std one char a time, all at once (C)

Tags: c, io, stdin

Is there a way to receive input from stdin one character at a time but entered in all at once. For example, I want to read in the value 654321. But I don't want to read in the entire thing at once. I want to read in the 6 first, do something with it and then come back for the 5. However the user, or redirected input file wouldn't have to press enter multiple times. They would just have to enter 654321 all at once followed by an enter.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store it at the start and then use one character at a time for your logic?

Comment: I want to toss the integer in this case into a linked list but the input could be 90 million integers long for all I know.

Comment: I mean if you just scanf or get input somehow the rest won't go away, it will stay in the queue and you can scan again on the next loop.

Comment: Consider `getchar()`

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

As posted by @chux above, the answer I was looking for was getchar().